# Ruby - Gems Env - Encoding Error (windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I have installed the latest Ruby version from RubyInstaller on Windows and then installed Rails through gems.

Everytime I try to run `rails new app_name` command I get an encoding error.

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:52:in `match?': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:52:in `chop_basename'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:376:in `plus'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:356:in `+'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:422:in `join'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/settings.rb:445:in `global_config_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/settings.rb:93:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:343:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:343:in `settings'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/env.rb:20:in `report'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:71:in `request_issue_report_for'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:50:in `log_error'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:115:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/exe/bundle:36:in `<main>'
```

I suspected something was probably wrong with my PATH's so I checked my `gem env` and I saw that the problem lies in my Windows User folder name which has a special character in it and apparently ruby does not accept it, find below my gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.3.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.1.2 (2022-04-12 patchlevel 20) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/Tiago Galv�o/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd/git.EXE
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby31-x64/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/Tiago Galv�o/.local/share/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
```

I have tried to change my User folder name trough the windows registry and the commands indeed start working. However I needed to revert everything to the original name because my system started acting strange.

**So my question is:**

- How can I change the USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY and SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY of my `gem env` in order to be able to run rails commands in Windows? I would like to change the folder to a folder without any special chars or even to make ruby accept this special char in my name.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in Ruby, or more specifically Bundler. I would report it as a bug.

In the meantime you can try setting `GEM_HOME`. It should be the base setting for the rest of the folders. There is also `GEM_SPEC_CACHE`, which allows you to move the cache folder separately.

However the error you are getting is from Bundler, when it is running [`global_config_file`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/28e27ee76eb7aa79cc2b6c7fe6ce6cf3acc32dc7/lib/bundler/settings.rb#L437).

From there we can see that you might want to set `BUNDLE_CONFIG` or `BUNDLE_USER_CONFIG`. I looks like it may be enough just to set one of these to point to a dummy location. For example `C:\Dummy`. This will prevent Bundler from trying to access your user home directory, which is the one with the problematic UTF-8 character.

One of those env variables, or a combination of them, will hopefully allow everything to work.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! How can I change those variables ?

Comment: Read the post below. You can set them locally in the current command prompt (good for testing) or globally in the registry.  https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt

Comment: should that empty file be .env file?

Comment: Actually reading the code more carefully I see you do not even need the file. Just set the `BUNDLE_CONFIG` env variable to for example `C:/Blah` and give it a try. I think it should be enough that it is set. No file is needed.

Answer (score 0):

rubyinstaller takes a DIR argument

```
rubyinstaller-w.x.y-z-x64.exe /DIR="%ProgramFiles%\Ruby"
```

Comment: The problem doesn’t  seem  to be with ruby install dir but instead with user installation directory and spec cache directory. Because the ruby install path does not have any special chars. Actually it is my user folder that has a special char as my name is “Tiago Galvão”. And since windows does not allow you to change your user folder name… I am trying to find ways to change the encoding in order to make ruby accept the path name.